# How to generate sounds by frequency in Java?

Tags: java, audio, frequency

How do I generate my own sound by frequency in Java?

I can play [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) files or [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) files, but now I don't need this. I want to create a simple guitar program, and I want to play chords with this program. But I don't know how to make the sounds to the chords. I can record them with my own guitar, but this is not what I want, I want to generate the sounds!

What would some example code look like?

Comment: Do you want to create simple (sine, rect, ...) sounds by frequency or do you want to create guitar sounds (sine with overtones and some distortion)?

Comment: Both of them!
First some simple sound, like Em, C, A#, etc... not chords, only one sound. 
But I would love to make distortion sounds too, if it's possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guitar sounds are usually synthesized in software using some variant of the [Karplus-Strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karplus-Strong_string_synthesis) algorithm.  There are numerous libraries for audio output depending on your requirements, but you could [start with `javax.sound.sampled`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html).

Comment: Will [this](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/samples/JavaSoundDemo/) help?

Comment: thanks! it's wonderfull! now I have to look into the codes and find out how to generate my own sounds!

Comment: Good luck!  This is a cool thing to be experimenting with (imho), make sure you keep your volume low when testing!!